# Low GPU usage when training a CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I just installed tensorflow gpu and I started to train my convolutional neural network. The problem is that my gpu usage percentage is constantly at 0% and sometimes it increases until 20%. The CPU is somewhere at 20% and the disk above 60%. I tried to test if I installed it correctly and I done some matrix multiplications, in that case, everything was allright and the GPU usage was above 90%.

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    #here I set up the computational graph
```

when I run the graph I use this, so the compiler will decide if one operation has a gpu implementation or not

```
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
```

I have an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 950m graphic card and I don't get errors at runtime. What am I doing wrong?

later edit, my computation graph

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels], name="X")
    dropout_rate= 0.3


    training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=(), name="training")
    X_drop = tf.layers.dropout(X, dropout_rate, training = training)

    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None], name="y")


    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X_drop, filters=32, kernel_size=3,
                            strides=1, padding="SAME",
                            activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv1")

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters=64, kernel_size=3,
                            strides=2, padding="SAME",
                            activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv2")

    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2,
                            ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                            strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                            padding="VALID")

    conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool3, filters=128, kernel_size=4,
                            strides=3, padding="SAME",
                            activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv4")

    pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4,
                            ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                            padding="VALID")


    pool5_flat = tf.reshape(pool5, shape = [-1, 128*2*2])

    fullyconn1 = tf.layers.dense(pool5_flat, 128, activation=tf.nn.relu, name = "fc1")
    fullyconn2 = tf.layers.dense(fullyconn1, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu, name = "fc2")

    logits = tf.layers.dense(fullyconn2, 2, name="output")

    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

hm_epochs = 100
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

the batch size is 128

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        tbWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter(logPath, sess.graph)
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((training_images, training_labels))
        dataset = dataset.map(rd.decodeAndResize)
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

        testset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
        testset = testset.map(rd.decodeAndResize)
        testset = testset.batch(len(test_images))

        iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
        test_iterator = testset.make_initializable_iterator()
        next_element = iterator.get_next()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            sess.run(iterator.initializer)
            while True:
                try:
                    epoch_x, epoch_y = sess.run(next_element)
                    # _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                    # epoch_loss += c
                    sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X:epoch_x, y:epoch_y, training:True})
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                    break


            sess.run(test_iterator.initializer)
            # acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X:epoch_x, y:epoch_y})
            try:
                next_test = test_iterator.get_next()
                test_images, test_labels = sess.run(next_test)
                acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X:test_images, y:test_labels})
                print("Epoch {0}: Train accuracy {1}".format(epoch, acc_test))
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
            # print("Epoch {0}: Train accuracy {1}, Test accuracy: {2}".format(epoch, acc_train, acc_test))
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_first_model")
```

I have 9k training pictures and 3k pictures for testing

Comment: There can be many reasons for this, and it is impossible to tell exactly what the reason is without more details and code. One possible explanation is that feeding and preparing your input data batches takes a lot of time (this is typically done on the CPU). Meanwhile, the GPU is idle waiting for something to work on.

Comment: hi mikkola, thank you for your reply. I edited the post and added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code that may result in low GPU usage.

1) Add a [`prefetch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) instruction at the end of your `Dataset` pipeline to enable the CPU to maintain a buffer of input data batches ready to move them to the GPU.

```
# this should be the last thing in your pipeline
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
```

2) You are using `feed_dict` to feed your model, along with `Dataset` iterators. This is not the intended way! [`feed_dict` is the slowest method of inputting data to your model and not recommended](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#Feeding). You should define your *model* in terms of the `next_element` outputs of the iterators.

Example:

```
next_x, next_y = iterator.get_next()
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(next_x, filters=32, kernel_size=3,
                        strides=1, padding="SAME",
                        activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv1")
    # rest of model here...
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, 
                 labels=next_y)
```

Then you can call your training operation *without* using `feed_dict`, and the iterator will handle feeding data to your model behind the scenes. [Here is another related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053569/tensorflow-create-minibatch-from-numpy-array-2-gb/49054290#49054290). Yout new training loop would look something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={training:True})
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```

You should only input data via `feed_dict` that your iterator does not provide, and these should typically be very lightweight.

For further tips on performance, you can refer to [this guide on TF website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/performance/datasets_performance).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I will change those things and I will come back with an answer.

Comment: I have a question. If I intagrate the iterator in my computation graph, how can I feed in the testing data?

Comment: @LaciSzakács you can use a re-initializable or feedable iterator. Check out the in-depth guide here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator

Comment: I managed to use a re-initializable iterator. Now my usage percentage grows till 20% periodically... but still does not use 100% of my gpu :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code to see if tensorflow is  recognizing your GPU:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried that code and tensorflow recognized my gtx gpu card